# How to let user enter her birthdate in flutter app

Tags: flutter, datepicker

In flutter app when user clicks on birthdate field, the app should show a date picker at bottom and when clicked on done the date should show up in date field.
I am trying to use flutter_cupertino_date_picker but I couldnt find an example that displays the datepicker on click and then hides it after reading the date.

Answer (score 0):

Following things are provided with this widget:

1. A custom textfield to allow users to enter date - 'MM-dd-yyyy'
2. A calendar icon to allow users to pick a date
3. `getDate` func that is called by parent widget to get date in 2 different string formats.
4. Text is colored red when enter date is invalid. Text is green when its valid.
5. Regex is used to retrict user from entering non data format. This part can be improved coz currently user can also enter '11111' although it will still be red and return blank string to `getDate()` function

[image: Blank date field]
[image: Wrong date]
[image: correct date]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:xyz/utils/pixel_sizes.dart';

class MyDatePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  final String labelText;
  final Function(String, String) getDate;

  const MyDatePicker({this.labelText = 'Enter date', required this.getDate, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyDatePicker> createState() => _MyDatePickerState();
}

class _MyDatePickerState extends State<MyDatePicker> {
  TextEditingController dateInput = TextEditingController();
  bool? isInputDateValidFormat; // True when valid, false when invalid, null in begining

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double fontSize = bodyMediumFontSize(context);
    const String dtRegex = "^[0-9]{0,2}-?[0-9]{0,2}-?[0-9]{0,4}";

    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                  firstDate: DateTime(1900), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
                  lastDate: DateTime(2101));

              if (pickedDate != null) {
                print(pickedDate); //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
                String dateForDisplay = convertDateToDisplayFormat(pickedDate);
                String dateForDb = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickedDate);
                print('dateForDisplay=$dateForDisplay'); //formatted date output using intl package =>  2021-03-16
                print('dateForDb=$dateForDb');
                //you can implement different kind of Date Format here according to your requirement

                setState(() {
                  print('IconButton setState');
                  dateInput.text = dateForDisplay; //set output date to TextField value.
                  widget.getDate(dateForDisplay, dateForDb);
                });
              } else {
                print("Date is not selected");
              }
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month_outlined),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: fontSize * 15,
            child: TextField(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: isInputDateValidFormat != null
                    ? isInputDateValidFormat == true
                        ? Colors.green
                        : Colors.red
                    : Colors.black,
              ),
              inputFormatters: [
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(dtRegex)),
              ],
              //FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow((RegExp(dtFinalRegex)))
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
                labelText: widget.labelText,
              ),
              controller: dateInput,
              onChanged: (dateForDisplay) {
                setState(() {
                  print('newdateStr =$dateForDisplay');
                  try {
                    DateTime parseDate = DateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").parse(dateForDisplay);
                    print('Datetime=$parseDate');
                    String dateForDb = convertDateToDbFormat(parseDate);
                    if (checkMonthLimit(dateForDisplay) == true && checkYearLength(dateForDisplay) == true) {
                      isInputDateValidFormat = true;
                      widget.getDate(dateForDisplay, dateForDb);
                    } else {
                      throw const FormatException('Bad data');
                    }
                  } on FormatException catch (e) {
                    isInputDateValidFormat = false;
                    widget.getDate('', '');
                    return;
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

String convertDateToDbFormat(DateTime dt) {
  // convert datetime obj to database compatible date format
  return DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(dt);
}

String convertDateToDisplayFormat(DateTime dt) {
  // convert datetime obj to display compatible date format
  return DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy').format(dt);
}

bool checkMonthLimit(String dateForDisplay) {
  // Dart dateformat is stupid. It will convert month 15 to january. so we need to do extra verifications
  return int.parse(dateForDisplay.split("-")[0]) <= 12;
}

bool checkYearLength(String dateForDisplay) {
  // Dart dateformat is stupid. year "2" becomes 0002 which is BS.
  return dateForDisplay.split("-")[2].length == 4;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Import package `flutter_cupertino_date_picker` as per [Link here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupertino_date_picker)

In a statefull widget create a datetime variable

```
DateTime birthDate;
```

Then in your column add this expanded widget:

```
Expanded(
              child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    this.birthDate == null
                        ? 'Birthdate'
                        : '${this.birthDate.year}-${this.birthDate.month}-${this.birthDate.day}',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600]),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    DatePicker.showDatePicker(
                      context,
                      initialDateTime: this.birthDate,
                      onConfirm: (newDate, listOfIndexes) {
                        setState(() {
                          this.birthDate = newDate;
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

When birthdate text field is clicked, a date picker pops up at bottom and whatever date is selected is shown in the date field